# Record-view-form doesn't support Time data type field to be displayed

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-recordviewform

According to documentation of lightning-output-field which is used in lighting-record-view Time is not Support Record Type. So if we want to display time field in lightning-record-view we can't. Do we have any other component to display time field. here is list of fields supported in lightning-output-field

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-output-field/documentation

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can create our own component and use them inside lightning-record-view-form to display time data type.
outputTime.html

```
<template>
    <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="text-input-id-1">{_fieldLabel}</label>
    <output id="text-input-id-1" class="slds-show" >{timeValue}</output>
</template>
```

outputTime.js

```
import { LightningElement, api, track,wire } from 'lwc';
import LOCALE from '@salesforce/i18n/locale';
import { getRecord  } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import { getObjectInfo } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';

export default class OutputTime extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
    @track _fieldApiName;
    @track _value;
    _objectName;
    _fieldName;
    _fieldLabel;
    @api
    get fieldApiName() {
        return this._fieldApiName;
    };
    set fieldApiName(value) {
        this._fieldApiName = value;
        if(this._fieldApiName){
            this._objectName = this._fieldApiName.split('.')[0];
            this._fieldName = this._fieldApiName.split('.')[1];
        } else {
            this._objectName = undefined;
            this._fieldName = undefined;
        }
    };
    @wire(getRecord,{recordId: '$recordId',fields: '$_fieldApiName'})
    objRec({error, data}) {
        if (data) {
            this._value = data.fields[this._fieldName].value;
        } else {
            this.error = error;
        }
    }
    @wire(getObjectInfo,{objectApiName: '$_objectName'})
    objectInfo({error, data}) {
        if (data) {
            this._fieldLabel = data.fields[this._fieldName].label;
        } else {
            this._fieldLabel = '';
        }
    }
    get timeValue() {
        if(this._value && this._value.split(':').length > 2){
            let formated = new Intl.DateTimeFormat(LOCALE, {timeStyle: "medium"}).format(new Date(2020, 1, 1, this._value.split(':')[0], (this._value.split(':')[1]).split('.')[0], 0));
            return formated;
        } else {
            return '';
        }
    }
}
```

This component will display different format time depending upon your ***locale***.
We don't need to worry about timezones because **Time field like Date field is not dependent on timeZone**. Because we need both time and date to apply timezones to change date and time.

So to use this component in lightning-record-view here is an example

```
<lightning-record-view-form
            record-id={recordId}
            object-api-name="Account">
        <div class="slds-box">
            <lightning-output-field field-name="Name">
            </lightning-output-field>
            <c-output-time record-id={recordId} field-api-name="Account.Customtime__c"></c-output-time>
        </div>
    </lightning-record-view-form>
```

We have to pass recordId and **fieldApiName which is equal to "objectname.fieldName".**

This component will work **with or without lightning-record-view-form**.